# JavaPropsMapper in com.fasterxml.jackson version 2.14.2

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I did an upgrade of `com.fasterxml.jackson` from `2.8.8` to `2.14.2` but I noticed that the following code will not work in version `2.14.2` :

```
 //where javaPropsMapper is an instance of com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsMapper;
 // and Properties is from java.util.Properties

 Properties prop = new Properties();
 properties.setProperty("a.key", "value");
 JsonNode result = javaPropsMapper.readValue(prop, JsonNode.class);
```

the above code in version 2.14.2 does not compile because there is no method javaPropsMapper.readValue that accepts these arguments anymore.

In version 2.8.8 the output would be a JsonNode like this: `{"a":{"key":"value"}}`

Please let me know if you have any hints/info or an alternative way to do it.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
public <T> T readPropertiesAs(Properties props,
                     Class<T> valueType)
                   throws IOException
```

[`Full example`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformats-text/javadoc/properties/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/javaprop/JavaPropsMapper.html#readPropertiesAs(java.util.Properties,%20java.lang.Class))

Comment: This seems to be the right way to do it but I am having this error now : `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
 com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsFactory._createContentReference(Ljava/lang/Object;)
 Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/ContentReference; at 
 com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsFactory.createParser(JavaPropsFactory.java:157) at 
 com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsMapper.readPropertiesAs(JavaPropsMapper.java:107) at 
 com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.javaprop.JavaPropsMapper.readPropertiesAs(JavaPropsMapper.java:141) at `

Comment: This looks like a problem with other dependencies. I answered your question - please accept my answer and ask another question.